# Why doesn't this reflection algorithm work?

Tags: javascript, graphics, vector, transformation, linear-algebra

I wanted to make a reflection algorithm that avoided the sqrt function, and this is what I came up with:

```
Vector3D.prototype.reflectOver = function(vectorToReflectOver){ //return a reflected vector
    var t = (vectorToReflectOver.dot(vectorToReflectOver))/(this.dot(vectorToReflectOver));

    var reflectedVector = vectorToReflectOver.multiply(2).subtract(this.multiply(t));

    return reflectedVector;
}
```

The reasoning behind it is that if we want to reflect a vector V_1 over another vector V_2, we want to find a vector V_3 such that V_2 + V_3 is the reflection vector. First we must find the vector t*V_1 such that t*V_1 - V_2 = V_3. This is what t is in the function. Any ideas?

Just to be clear, the dot function refers to a dot product, multiply multiplies a scalar to a vector, subtract subtracts two vectors. The function is called like so, v.reflectOver(n), where v and n are two vectors. Furthermore, this doesn't throw an error. This is a performance error, not a compiler or runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to say where you went wrong, but if you draw it out on paper, you should get something like this:

```
this.project_onto(other.as_unit_vector()).multiply(2).subtract(this)
```